# Python threading daemon error when extending Thread class

Tags: python, multithreading

I've been trying to extend my Thread class to return something from a target function but I want to keep the daemon = True. The default daemon is False so I need to pass the True value into the `Thread.__init__()` and when I try: `__init__() takes from 1 to 6 positional arguments but 7 were given`
Here's the code:

```
class Thread1(Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
                 args=(), kwargs={}, daemon = None):
        Thread.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs, daemon)
        self._return = None

    def run(self):
        if self._target is not None:
            self._return = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    def join(self, *args):
        Thread.join(self, *args)
        return self._return
```

I've tried to remove the self parameter but it doesn't work then.

Comment: What is the point of setting `daemon=True` on a thread that is supposed to "return" a value?

Comment: I need it because i use a GUI to run the thread and i want to be able to stop the thread with a STOP button included in the GUI ( STOP button stops the main thread ).